# How to make sense of Joda-Time key class DateTime and LocalDateTime

Tags: java

[Joda time quick start guide](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html)
says that there are 5 key datetime classes: one is DateTime, another is **LocalDateTime**(which has no time zone) and somether others. According to this quick guide, **LocalDateTime** has no time zone, who can give me a detail explanation of ***time*** which has no time zone? what's its(time has no time zone) internal format? This ***time*** concept is really important to me, please help me, many thanks.

Comment: I suspect that a `DateTime` without time zone will take what ever values you give it blindly and won't try applying any modifications to it based in your current local, where as a `DateTime` with a Time Zone will always try and correct the values to that time zone...but I'm only guessing...

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking but, as per the [docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) I feel that LocalDateTime does not support time zone information and all the instances created does not hold any time zone data. However, for internal calculation all the dates are assigned UTC as time zone. Hope this clears some clouds.

Comment: What i really what to know is whether time with no time zone means utc or not, if this is true, there will no clouds any more.

Comment: No, I don' think time with no time zone can be considered as UTC. I think that you can supply EST to LocalDateTime without time zone info and it will internally use UTC for calculation purpose but that does not mean that it will convert the EST to UTC.